# Unusual behavior DropDownList MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I managed to populate DropDownList with value from a Database in ASP.NET MVC 5. My goal is to assing one of the dropDownList's value to a specific model, and send it back to the Database. So, if i leave the default value in the dropdownlist, the data in SQL server is null, which is Okay, but if I  choose an option, I get an error : 
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll ("There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Status'."). I tried everything so far and i am opened for suggestions. Thank you !!! 
In Controller :

```
ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.Status, "Id", "Name");
```

in   View

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Status","Select status...")
```

In Controller so far..

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
         [HttpGet]
         public ActionResult Apply(ViewModelVM vm,int x=0)
         {
            myDb db = new myDb();
            ViewBag.SocialStatus = new SelectList(db.SocialStatuses, "Id", "StatusDescription");
            return View();
         }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Apply(ViewModelVM vm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (myDb db = new myDb())
                {
                    var personalinfo = new PersonalInformation()
                    {
                        FirstName = vm.PersonalInformation.FirstName,
                        LastName = vm.PersonalInformation.LastName,
                        Birthdate = vm.PersonalInformation.Birthdate,
                        SocialStatus = vm.SocialStatus
                    };
                    ViewBag.SocialStatus = new SelectList(db.SocialStatuses, "Id", "StatusDescription");
                    db.PersonalInformations.Add(personalinfo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return View("Success");
                }

            return View();
        }
```

The model:

```
public partial class Status
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public SocialStatus()
        {
            PersonalInformations = new HashSet<PersonalInformation>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalInformation> PersonalInformations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModelVM
    {
        ...
        public Status SocialStatus { set; get; }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Because the value of `Status` is `null` (probably because your returning the view from the POST action).

Comment: Yes, I do, but what is the proper solution to this problem if so ? I stuck in this problem for ages... I will highly appreciate you help :)

Comment: Do you have a property in your model named `Status`? How do current populate the collection in the GET method? (you need to show the relevant code)

Comment: After post request you want to redirect user somewhere? If not you stay on the same form - so you need fill the ViewBag.Status again in POST action

Comment: Edit your question! (not in comments)

Comment: and add your POST action method

Comment: Still have the same issues..

Comment: You still have not shown your model (you don't even appear to have a property named `Status`)

Comment: It is SocialStatus, but I renamed it for another reason, just assume its SocialStatus istead of Status everywhere. I feel desperate ..

Comment: There is no point posting the wrong code and saying it does not work! (I have edited your question). There are multiple problems with your code so I will add an answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you. This means a lot for me.  I will be very grateful if you tell me where are these problems, without taking in mind "SocialStatus" ones.

Comment: The `SocialStatus` one is critical to your problems!

Comment: I realize that, but i replaced on purpose for stackoverflow. In VS my code is well named, just i can't choose SocialStatus, and send it back to MSSQL. I Will wait for you to review my code. Thank you one more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your using a view model so include a property in your view model for the `SelectList`

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
```

Next remove the parameter for the model from the GET method (and since you don't appear to be using the value of `x`, that should be removed also)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Apply(ViewModelVM vm,int x=0)
{
  myDb db = new myDb();
  ViewModelVM model = new ViewModelVM()
  {
    StatusList = new SelectList(db.SocialStatuses, "Id", "StatusDescription");
  };
  return View(model); // return the model to the view
}
```

Next, your dropdown is binding to a property named `Status` but your view model does not contain a property named status (its `SocialStatus`) and `SocialStatus` is a complex object and you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (a `<select>` only posts back a single value (or array or values in the case of `<select multiple>`).

In addition, because your view model contains a property which is a complex object with validation attributes on its properties, `ModelState` will always be invalid because you do not post back a value for `StatusDescription`. As a result you always return the view in the POST method, and because you have not reassigned `ViewBag.Status = ....`, it is `null`, hence the error.

Remove property `public Status SocialStatus { set; get; }` and include

```
[Display(Name = "Social Status")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a status")]
public int SocialStatus { get; set; }
```

an then in the view, strongly bind to your model using

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SocialStatus)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SocialStatus, Model.StatusList, "-Please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SocialStatus)
```

Then, in the POST method, if `ModelState` is invalid, populate the select list again before returning the view

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  model.StatusList = new SelectList(db.SocialStatuses, "Id", "StatusDescription");
  return View(model);
}
// save and redirect
```

Finally, review [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).